# Reshape an activity log in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have an activity log stored in a data frame that records the times when agents are on a phone call:

```
Agent   | Call Start |  Call End
--------------------------------
Albert  | 9:33:31    | 9:38:30

Albert  | 9:40:33    | 9:44:36

Boris   | 9:27:39    | 9:36:39
```

etc.

I would like to reshape the data so that I can see which agents are occupied or available during any period across the day:

```
From    |   To      |   Albert |    Boris
-----------------------------------
9:00:01 | 9:27:38   | Free     | Free

9:27:39 | 9:33:30   | Free     | Occupied

9:33:31 | 9:36:39   | Occupied | Occupied

9:36:39 | 9:38:30   | Occupied | Free
```

etc.

I am looking to do this with `tidyverse` tools if possible, but open to whatever works!

Comment: Where did you get time `9:30:01`? Why it's before `9:27:38`?

Comment: It was a typo.  I will edit it.

Comment: I'm thinking along the following lines:
For each transaction record create a vector of times (in seconds) from Call Start to Call End
Combine the vectors for each agent into a single vector
Join that vector to a vector of seconds between the day's start time and it's end time.
If the vector for the agent matches the vector of all seconds, the Agent is set to Occupied; if not it is marked as free.

Sounds good in theory but I am concerned of (a) performance and (b) how to perform across both multiple agents and multiple dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - here's an answer that heavily utilises packages and functions from the tidyverse, in particular the spread and gather functions.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(chron)
library(zoo)

#Create sample activity log
Agent <- c('Albert','Albert','Boris','Boris','Charlie','Charlie','Charlie')
Call_Start <- times(c('9:33:31','9:40:33','9:27:39','9:41:23','9:19:09','9:35:28','9:46:31')) #use chron function
Call_End <- times(c('9:38:30','9:44:36','9:36:39','9:42:29','9:19:19','9:45:28','9:46:55'))
Start <- data.frame(Agent,Call_Start,Call_End)

#Set the Start and End times for the Day 
start_time <- times(c('09:00:01'))
end_time <- times(c('17:00:01'))

#Create the specific time breaks needed
Time_breaks_start <- sort(c(start_time,Start$Call_Start,Start$Call_End))
Time_breaks_end <- sort(c(Start$Call_Start, Start$Call_End,end_time))
Time_breaks <- data.frame(Time_breaks_start,Time_breaks_end)

#Use gather and spread to identify when agents start and end calls.
Gathered <- Start %>% 
  gather(key="Start_End",value="Time_breaks_start", Call_Start, Call_End) %>% 
  mutate(Start_End = ifelse(Start_End == 'Call_Start','Occupied','Free'))
Spread <- Gathered %>% 
        spread(key=Agent, value=Start_End)

#Join spread data to list of time breaks and clean up missing values
Output <- Time_breaks %>% 
      left_join(Spread, by='Time_breaks_start') %>%
      do(na.locf(.)) %>% #uses function from zoo
      apply(2, function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- "Free" ; x })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I'm not very up on `tidyverse` but this should produce your desired result.

```
x    
 Agent Call_Start Call_End
1 Albert    9:33:31  9:38:30
2 Albert    9:40:33  9:44:36
3  Boris    9:27:39  9:36:39

x$Call_Start<-as.POSIXct(x$Call_Start, format=("%H:%M:%S"))
x$Call_End<-as.POSIXct(x$Call_End, format=("%H:%M:%S"))

#create a list of times to check 
start<-as.POSIXct("09:27:00", format=("%H:%M:%S"))
end<-as.POSIXct("09:45:00", format=("%H:%M:%S"))

t<-seq.POSIXt(start, end, by="sec")

#create a dataframe to hold the results
agents<-unique(x$Agent)

occ_dat<-data.frame(matrix(nrow=length(t), ncol=length(agents)+1))

occ_dat[,1]<-t

names(occ_dat)<-c("time", as.character(agents))

#divide the data up by agent
each_agent<-split(x, f=x$Agent)

#check for each agent whether or not they were occupied at each time
sil<-sapply(seq_along(agents), function(i){

  c_agent<-each_agent[[i]]

  apply(c_agent, 1, function(call){

    occ_dat[,(i+1)]<<-ifelse(occ_dat$time>=call[2] & 
                         occ_dat$time<=call[3], "occupied", occ_dat[,(i+1)])
  })
})

#if agent is not occupied set them to "free"
occ_dat[is.na(occ_dat)]<-"free"

#collapse all times into non-overlapping time periods by giving a unique ID
#every time either agent has a status change

occ_dat$status<-1

counter<-1

occ_dat$status[2:nrow(occ_dat)]<-sapply(2:nrow(occ_dat), function(i){
  if(occ_dat[i,2]==occ_dat[i-1,2] &
     occ_dat[i,3]==occ_dat[i-1,3]) {counter}
  else {counter<<-counter+1; counter}
})

#use duplicated to get the start and end of each unique status period and combine
od1<-occ_dat[!duplicated(occ_dat$status),]

od2<-occ_dat[!duplicated(occ_dat$status, fromLast = TRUE),]

od3<-merge(od1, od2[,c("time", "status")], by="status")

#some formatting
od3<-od3[,c(2,5,3,4)]
names(od3)[1:2]<-c("From", "To")

od3
               From                  To   Albert    Boris
1 2018-06-05 09:27:00 2018-06-05 09:27:38     free     free
2 2018-06-05 09:27:39 2018-06-05 09:33:30     free occupied
3 2018-06-05 09:33:31 2018-06-05 09:36:39 occupied occupied
4 2018-06-05 09:36:40 2018-06-05 09:38:30 occupied     free
5 2018-06-05 09:38:31 2018-06-05 09:40:32     free     free
6 2018-06-05 09:40:33 2018-06-05 09:44:36 occupied     free
7 2018-06-05 09:44:37 2018-06-05 09:45:00     free     free
```